# How do I apply BlurEffect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect) twice?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

I have this code

```
import sys                                                         # +++
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


'''
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''



class BlurEffect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect):
    effectRect = None

    def setEffectRect(self, rect):
        self.effectRect = rect
        self.update()

    def draw(self, qp):
        if self.effectRect is None or self.effectRect.isNull():
            # no valid effect rect to be used, use the default implementation
            super().draw(qp)
            print('bao')
        else:
            qp.save()
            # clip the drawing so that it's restricted to the effectRect
            qp.setClipRect(self.effectRect)
            # call the default implementation, which will draw the effect
            super().draw(qp)
            # get the full region that should be painted
            fullRegion = QtGui.QRegion(qp.viewport())
            # and subtract the effect rectangle
            fullRegion -= QtGui.QRegion(self.effectRect)
            qp.setClipRegion(fullRegion)
            # draw the *source*, which has no effect applied
            self.drawSource(qp)
            qp.restore()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        background = QtGui.QPixmap('background.png')

        # apply a background to this widget, note that this only serves for the
        # graphics effect to know what's outside the boundaries
        p = self.palette()
        p.setBrush(p.Window, QtGui.QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(p)

        self.resize(background.size())

        # this layout is only for the child "sub" widget
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # the "sub" widget, that contains the main interface
        self.subWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.subWidget)
        # set the background for the subwidget; note that we can't use setPalette()
        # because palette and fonts are inherited by children; using ".QWidget"
        # we ensure that the background is only applied to the subwidget
        self.subWidget.setStyleSheet('''
            .QWidget {
                background-image: url(background.png);
            }
        ''')

        # some random widgets
        subLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.subWidget)
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                subLayout.addWidget(btn, row, col)

        btn.setText('Open menu')
        btn.setFocus()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.openMenu)

        # create an instance of our effect subclass, and apply it to the subwidget
        self.effect = BlurEffect()
        self.subWidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)
        self.effect.setEnabled(False)
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(10)









        # create the menu container, that *HAS* to have this main widget as parent
        self.topMenu = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.topMenu.setVisible(False)
        self.topMenu.setFixedWidth(200)
        # move the menu outside the window left margin
        self.topMenu.move(-self.topMenu.width(), 0)

        menuLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.topMenu)
        menuLayout.addSpacing(20)
        for b in range(4):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button {}'.format(b + 1))
            menuLayout.addWidget(btn)

        menuLayout.addSpacing(10)

        closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close menu')
        menuLayout.addWidget(closeButton)
        closeButton.clicked.connect(self.closeMenu)
        # a stretch to ensure that the items are always aligned on top
        menuLayout.addStretch(1)

        # an animation that will move the menu laterally
        self.menuAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.menuAnimation.setDuration(500)
        self.menuAnimation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutQuart)
        self.menuAnimation.setStartValue(-self.topMenu.width())
        self.menuAnimation.setEndValue(0)
        self.menuAnimation.valueChanged.connect(self.resizeMenu)
        self.menuAnimation.finished.connect(self.animationFinished)

        # a simple transparent widget that is used to hide the menu when
        # clicking outside it; the event filter is to capture click events
        # it may receive
        self.clickGrabber = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.clickGrabber.installEventFilter(self)
        self.clickGrabber.setVisible(False)

    def resizeMenu(self, value):
        # move the menu and set its geometry to the effect
        self.topMenu.move(value, 0)
        self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())

    def openMenu(self):
        if self.topMenu.x() >= 0:
            # the menu is already visible
            return
        # ensure that the menu starts hidden (that is, with its right border
        # aligned to the left of the main widget)
        self.topMenu.move(-self.topMenu.width(), 0)
        self.topMenu.setVisible(True)
        self.topMenu.setFocus()

        # enable the effect, set the forward direction for the animation, and
        # start it; it's important to set the effect rectangle here too, otherwise
        # some flickering might show at the beginning
        self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())
        self.effect.setEnabled(True)
        self.menuAnimation.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Forward)
        self.menuAnimation.start()

        # "show" the grabber (it's invisible, but it's there) and resize it
        # to cover the whole window area
        self.clickGrabber.setGeometry(self.rect())
        self.clickGrabber.setVisible(True)
        # ensure that it is stacked under the menu and above everything else
        self.clickGrabber.stackUnder(self.topMenu)

    def closeMenu(self):
        # in case that the menu has changed its size, set again the "start" value
        # to its negative width, then set the animation direction to backwards
        # and start it
        self.menuAnimation.setStartValue(-self.topMenu.width())
        self.menuAnimation.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
        self.menuAnimation.start()
        # hide the click grabber
        self.clickGrabber.setVisible(False)

    def animationFinished(self):
        # if the animation has ended and the direction was backwards it means that
        # the menu has been closed, hide it and disable the effect
        if self.menuAnimation.direction() == QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward:
            self.topMenu.hide()
            self.effect.setEnabled(False)

    def focusNextPrevChild(self, next):
        if self.topMenu.isVisible():
            # a small hack to prevent tab giving focus to widgets when the
            # menu is visible
            return False
        return super().focusNextPrevChild(next)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.clickGrabber and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            # the grabber has been clicked, close the menu
            self.closeMenu()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        # always set the menu height to that of the window
        self.topMenu.setFixedHeight(self.height())
        # resize the grabber to the window rectangle, even if it's invisible
        self.clickGrabber.setGeometry(self.rect())
        if self.topMenu.isVisible():
            # resize the effect rectangle
            self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.resize(640, 570)  
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need to be able to apply blur effect to multiple widget at one time

And the problem is when I add

```
    self.effect2 = BlurEffect()
    self.subWidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
    self.effect2.setEnabled(False)
    self.effect2.setBlurRadius(10)
```

after

```
    self.effect = BlurEffect()
    self.subWidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)
    self.effect.setEnabled(False)
    self.effect.setBlurRadius(10)
```

I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\widgets\menu.py", line 157, in openMenu
>       self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\widgets\menu.py", line 15, in
>   setEffectRect
>       self.update() RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type BlurEffect has been deleted

Does anyone know how to fix this?

photoshop
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to apply 2 same effects? How should these effects be applied? that is, is an effect applied and the second applied to the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Only one effect can be applied at once on a widget (and after that, no effect can be applied on any of its children or parents), at least for QWidgets.

From [QWidget.setGraphicsEffect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect):

> If there already is an effect installed on this widget, QWidget **will delete the existing effect** before installing the new effect.

What happens is that as soon as you apply `self.effect2` on subWidget, `self.effect` is removed from it and actually deleted. In PyQt terms, it means that the python *object* still exists, but not its C++ counterpart.

### UPDATE

It seems that you still don't understand how a QGraphicsEffect works.
The effect is **NOT** applied on the widgets you see with the blurred background. It is applied on the underlying widget (`subWidget`, in this case), and only on the rectangle(s) specified using the geometries of the widgets. You could even set the `effectRect` to any rect you want, even without any other widgets other than `subWidget`.

If you need to apply the effect to more than one rectangle, then you should use `setClipRegion` and use a composite QRegion with it.
Assuming you will always use QWidgets as a reference for the effect, and that the effect will *always* be applied to a widget that occupies the whole area of the window, you can use a "watch list" of widgets that need to be tracked, and update the effect whenever their geometry change.

```
class BlurEffect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect):
    shouldEnable = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.watched = []

    def watchWidget(self, widget):
        widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.watched.append(widget)

    def unwatchWidget(self, widget):
        if widget in self.watched:
            self.watched.remove(widget)
            self.update()

    def setEnabled(self, enabled):
        # in case you want to manually disable the effect, keep track of
        # the selected behavior
        self.shouldEnable = enabled
        super().setEnabled(enabled)

    def draw(self, qp):
        rects = []
        for widget in self.watched:
            if widget.isVisible():
                rect = widget.rect()
                if rect.isNull():
                    continue
                # map the widget geometry to the window
                rect.translate(
                    widget.mapTo(widget.window(), QtCore.QPoint()))
                rects.append(rect)
            if not self.isEnabled() and self.shouldEnable:
                super().setEnabled(True)
        if not rects:
            # no valid rect to be used, disable the effect if we should
            if not self.shouldEnable:
                super().setEnabled(False)
            # otherwise, keep drawing the source with the effect applied
            # to the whole area of the widget
            else:
                self.drawSource(qp)
        else:
            qp.save()
            # create a region that includes all rects
            rectRegion = QtGui.QRegion()
            for rect in rects:
               rectRegion |= QtGui.QRegion(rect) 
            # clip the effect painting to the region
            qp.setClipRegion(rectRegion)
            # call the default implementation, which will draw the effect
            super().draw(qp)
            # get the full region that should be painted
            fullRegion = QtGui.QRegion(qp.viewport())
            # and subtract the effect rectangle used before
            fullRegion -= rectRegion
            qp.setClipRegion(fullRegion)
            # draw the *source*, which has no effect applied
            self.drawSource(qp)
            qp.restore()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        # update the effect whenever a widget changes its geometry or
        # becomes visible
        if event.type() in (QtCore.QEvent.Resize, QtCore.QEvent.Move, 
            QtCore.QEvent.Show) and source.isVisible():
                super().setEnabled(True)
                self.update()
        # if a widget is going to be deleted, remove it from the list
        # of watched list; this is **VERY** important
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DeferredDelete:
            self.unwatchWidget(source)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Important notes:

- you have to use `watchWidget` for any widget for which you want to see the effect, including the topMenu; again, this doesn't mean that the effect is applied to those widget, but that their geometry is used for that;
- obviously, there's no `setEffectRect` anymore;
- with this implementation the effect disables itself automatically if all the watched widgets are hidden or their geometry is null, which means that you don't need to call `self.effect.setEnabled()` anymore;
- even in this case (no watched widgets visible), you can still enable the effect to the *whole area* by explicitly calling setEnabled(True);

Finally, I strongly suggest you to carefully study this code (and the previous) and the documentation about both [QGraphicsEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html#details) and [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details) (including the [clipping](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#clipping) section and all the related pages), and create some *simple* tests and examples by yourself to better understand how they work, before attempting to do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So I can't create two blurry widgets self.topMenu and self.topMenu2 that are connected to self.subWidget?

Comment: @askqest what do you mean by "connected"? You can only have one graphics effect for widget (which includes child widgets: you can't set a graphics widget on a parent and another on one of its children).

Comment: If I can not apply setGraphicsEffect twice since it connects to subWidget and not to topMenu
Can I somehow copy the view from subWidget to another widget
for example
`self.subWidget2.setCopyViewWidget(self.subWidget)self.effect2 = BlurEffect() self.subWidget2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2) self.effect2.setEnabled(False) self.effect2.setBlurRadius(10)`

Comment: @askqest I don't understand, can you clarify? What do you mean with "copy the view"?

Comment: I don’t know well QT so I don’t know if this is possible but.
What if you create a widget FaceWidget and assign an image of the created one to it based on what you now display subWidget
and after you apply the effect to both widgets.
Itself FaceWidget  only rejects what it shows subWidget and inside it there are no commands other than copying.
FaceWidget and subWidget are neither a parent nor a child for each other
If you have any ideas how to make two [blurWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I09Ik.png) at the same time, please tell me

Comment: You are still making confusion on how the graphics effect work. The blur effect is **not** applied to the menus, but on the underlying subWidget. With my implementation the effect is applied *on the subWidget*, using the *geometry of the menu*. This means that you can also create multiple rectangles on which the effect is applied; to achieve that you'll need to use a composite QRegion that is the sum of multiple QRegions created from the sum of the rectangles you want to apply the effect to. But this would make things a bit more complex, especially if you still need the animation.

Comment: And if you pass it to BlurEffect() through an array. 

 `arr = {}
 def setEffectRect(self, rect):
  #self.effectRect = rect
  arr[key] = rect 
  self.update()
  
 def DeleteEfect(self, key):
  del arr[key]
  
 def draw(self, qp):
  for i in arr:
   val = arr[i]
   key = i
   setRegion = QtGui.QRegion(val)`

And update only the part to which the action is applied.

Comment: The GraphicsEffect updates the whole area of the widget it's applied to (the **whole** subWidget area!), if you "remove" a rectangle on which it was applied, that rectangle will be painted normally then.

Comment: I mean in
`arr = {'topWidget':QRect(-200, 0, 200, 30), 'topWidget2':QRect(-200, 0, 200, 30)}`
Save the geometry of both widgets
And update animations one by one or update only one and the second pass statically
And when the animations are no longer needed to apply the`DeleteEffect('name2')`
And thereby get two [blurwidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I09Ik.png) one time
I have never worked with QRegion so I don’t know how to do it right and whether it can be done at all.

Comment: You still don't understand. The effect is **NOT** applied to the menu widgets, it's applied to the subWidget, and it is always applied *at once* to the *whole* area of that subWidget, there is no "second pass". If you want to apply it to multiple rectangles you have to use QRegions with setClipRegion instead of QRect with setClipRect.

Comment: But setClipRegion already works in `qp.setClipRegion(fullRegion)` how then can i apply setClipRegion?

Comment: @askqest I'm writing you a partial answer, but I strongly suggest you to study more carefully how QPainter and QRegion work, and try to better understand how I implemented the painting.

Comment: I am trying to understand but setClipRegion and setClipRect can only be applied to one qp. I see no way to apply them twice
Maybe i need intersected  here, but all the examples are in #С and I don’t know how to use them in python

Comment: @askqest Please read the update. Even if all the examples in the docs are in C++ the functions and arguments are the same as they are in PyQt. Try to read "between the lines" and understand the concepts behind them, don't try to "copy the code".

Comment: I finally understood. maybe . if you replace the rows with 
`qp.setClipRect(qp.viewport()) fullRegion -= QtGui.QRegion(QRect(200, 0, 200, 570)) fullRegion -= QtGui.QRegion(QRect(410, 0, 200, 570)) `
I get two blurred widgets. I could not understand this because I thought that if there is `-=` in the expression,
then I thought that I would get something like this (). 
`QRect(0, 0, 640, 570) - QRect(200, 0, 200, 570) - QRect(410, 0, 200, 570) = QRect(610, 0, 240,-570)`
but i was wrong.
tell me if I got right.

Comment: I just received a notification. Thank you for the detailed answer.